# Fanatically following f...?

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-crosswords, printers-devilry

[image: Empty crossword grid]

Eighteen answers are **printer's devilry**, others are regular cryptic clues. Can you fill in the last word of the title?

**Across**
1. Kay's satisfied getting fortune (6)
4. Accelerate around place of internment (5,2)
8. Legendary actress who shaved her head to portray a G.I. escaped outbreak of disease (4)
12. Ancient building on an island where olives are grown and bats are hung (7)
13. Festival near Colorado turned over small amount of data (5)
14. Bull in Pamplona has shaved head and body (5)
15. Orphan girl's caretakers refusing to take sides (5)
16. Eighty-six famous terraced houses (4)
17. Io: "Me, one who sees patients at a clinic" (7)
19. Tech giant sheltered by top politicians (4)
20. Skins from animals the fashion designer twisted to make part of a belt? (8)
22. It's used to move a helicopter left or right (5)
26. The dam in a tan? Ding, 111 metres tall, is the largest in Egypt (5)
27. US rapper P.I. tits for his neighbours sometimes (8)
29. "One might eat you"? That sounds like nonsense! (4)
31. The UN: "A modus operandi included sending explosive devices by mail" (7)
33. A capital in Polynesia among others (4)
35. Algonquian fighters brought their tomato war (5)
37. "Happy" group having the 31 down? (5)
38. Relation where Chinatown takes place before Welles's debut (2-3)
39. Criminal (at a cop): "Caught me getting some white powder!" (7)
40. Every isotope of uranium I table (4)
41. After her post tin got a job at CERN (7)
42. Can West opt him art? Let's get outta here! (6)

**Down**
1. The villagers gavel I utera sap resent for defeating Shang Tsung (9)
2. Green (and wild) 14 down nap (6,3)
3. Bare popular pets (6)
5. They trained infantry bat taint? Hear I'd terrain (5)
6. Pan (i.e. A) ensued as the ship caught fire (4)
7. Unstable and mute, wild and out of control (7)
9. Member of ethnic group in European capital is sent back (5)
10. There isn't any spec if I... how? Non, the ticket, we can sit anywhere within this section (5)
11. They rode bikes in tan tag eon Sunday (6)
14. Theta's man, Ian, on a med because of the stripes on its back, is now extinct (6)
18. Refuse to match wager of over 50 đồng (4)
21. Foremost exemplaries among electric, extra lubricious swimmers? (4)
23. A row selected from fourth row downwards (9)
24. Transport vehicles for George Bernard to visit café in Casablanca? (9)
25. One can be in the air, rising higher (6)
27. The samurai agreed to follow this US president with words that confirm a new union (7)
28. Were the May to find out where the star was leading them? (6)
30. Guy with Ford vehicle and stylish hat (6)
31. US political maps are sometimes divided into Reds, Tates and Tates (5)
32. He could build a wall from what Frodo would have if he tended to his garden himself, from the ground up (5)
34. Chico and hare, brothers of grouch Omar X (5)
36. Foes' front close to downfall? Soviet-made weapon provides counter-air defence (4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The completed grid, with printer's devilry answers highlighted in blue:

> [image: Completed grid, printer's devilry clues highlighted blue]

Clue explanations:

> **Across**
>  1. Kay's satisfied getting **fortune** (6) **KISMET** = K IS MET
>  4. **Accelerate** around place of internment (5,2) **CLOCK UP** = C (around) + LOCK UP (place of internment)
>  8. **Legendary** actress who shaved her head to portray a G.I. escaped outbreak of disease (4) **EPIC** = EPI(-[demi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demi_Moore))C
>  12. **Ancient building on an island where olives are grown** and bats are hung (7) **[NURAGHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuraghe)** = *AREHUNG
>  13. Festival near Colorado turned over **small amount of data** (5) **[OCTET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing))** = (TET + CO)<
>  14. Bull in Pamplona has shaved head and **body** (5) **TORSO** = TORO ('Bull' in Pamplona, Spain) containing S(-haved)
>  15. **Orphan girl**'s caretakers refusing to take sides (5) **ANNIE** = (-n)ANNIE(-s)
>  16. **Eighty-six** famous terraced houses (4) **[OUST](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/51880/where-did-term-86-come)** = _OUS T_
>  *17. I**M A GP, I.E. S**omeone who sees patients at a clinic (7)*
>  19. **Tech giant** sheltered by top politicians (4) **OPPO** = _OP PO_
>  20. Skins from animals the fashion designer twisted to make **part of a belt**? (8) **ASTEROID** = A(-nimal)S + T(-h)E + DIOR<
>  22. It's used to move a helicopter left or right (5) **ROTOR** cdef (palindrome) + &lit!
>  *26. The dam in a**SWAN, S**tanding 111 metres tall, is the largest in Egypt (5)*
>  *27. US rapper Pit**BULL DOGS**its for his neighbours sometimes (8)*
>  29. **"One might eat you"?** That sounds like nonsense! (4) **CROC** = “CROCK”
>  *31. The Una**BOMBER’S** modus operandi included sending explosive devices by mail (7)*
>  33. A capital in Polynesia among others (4) **APIA** = A + P_ + [IA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/i.a.) &lit!
>  *35. Algonquian fighters brought their toma**HAWKS** to war (5)*
>  37. "Happy" group **having the [BLUES]**? (5) **UPSET** = UP (Happy) + SET (group)
>  38. **Relation** where Chinatown takes place before Welles's debut (2-3) **IN-LAW** (IN LA) + W_
>  39. Criminal (at a cop): "Caught me getting **some white powder!**" (7) **TAPIOCA** = ATACOP* containing I (me)
>  *40. Every isotope of uranium i**S UNS**table (4)*
>  *41. After her post-**DOC KERS**tin got a job at CERN (7)*
>  *42. Can we stop? Thi **S AIN’T S**mart! Let's get outta here! (6)*
>
>   **Down**
>  *1. The villagers gave Liu **KANG A ROOS**ter as a present for defeating Shang Tsung (9)*
>  2. **Green** (and wild) [TIGERS] nap (6,3) **STRING PEA** = TIGERSNAP*
>  *3. B**EAGLES** are popular pets (6)*
>  *5. They trained infantry batta**LIONS** in the arid terrain (5)*
>  *6. Pani**C AT S**ea ensued as the ship caught fire (4)*
>  7. Unstable and mute, **wild and out of control** (7) **UNTAMED** = ANDMUTE*
>  9. **Member of ethnic group** in European capital is sent back (5) **[PARSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsis)** = PAR(IS<)
>  *10. There isn't any specifi**C ROW S**hown on the ticket, we can sit anywhere within this section (5)*
>  *11. They rode bikes in tan**DEM ON S**tage on Sunday (6)*
>  *14. The tasmanian **TIGER - S**o-named because of the stripes on its back – is now extinct (6)*
>  18. **Refuse to match wager** of over 50 đồng (4) **FOLD** = OF< + L (fifty) + D (dong)
>  21. Foremost exemplaries among electric, extra lubricious swimmers? (4) **EELS** = E_ E_ L_ S_ &lit!
>  23. **A row** selected from fourth row downwards (9) **THROWDOWN** = _TH ROW DOWN_
>  24. **Transport vehicles** for George Bernard to visit café in Casablanca? (9) **RICKSHAWS** = RICK(SHAW)S
>  25. One can be in the air, **rising higher** (6) **ASCENT** = cdef (A SCENT) + def
>  27. **The samurai agreed to follow this** US president with words that confirm a new union (7) **BUSHIDO** = BUSH + I DO
>  *28. Were the Ma**GI ANTS**y to find out where the star was leading them? (6)*
>  30. Guy with Ford vehicle and **stylish hat** (6) **[CHAPKA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chapka)** = CHAP (Guy) + KA (Ford vehicle)
>  *31. US political maps are sometimes divided into Red States and **BLUE S**tates (5)*
>  32. **He could build a wall** from what Frodo would have if he tended to his garden himself, from the ground up (5) **MASON** = (NO SAM)<
>  *34. Chico and Har**PO WER**e, brothers of Groucho Marx (5)*
>  36. Foes' front close to downfall? Soviet-made weapon provides **counter-air defence** (4) **FLAK** = F(-oes) + (-fal)L + AK

The missing word in the title is:

> **FOOTBALL**! Since all 18 of the printer's devilry clues are the nicknames of teams in Australia's [Australian Rules Football League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Football_League).